# Plugins missing in Target Platform dependencies

Tags: java, osgi, iot, kura

I can't build and deploy the plugin application because the target platform has not important plugins as:

- javax.microedition
- javax.comm

The target platform is the ESF version 4.0.2 (available from this site http://www.eurotech.com/download/en/pb.aspx?pg=ESF%204.0.2)

For javax.microedition I fixed the problem downloading the jar and create the plugin manually and importing it in the target platform.

As for javax.comm I am not able to fix as the previous one.

I follow the serial example tutorial, but the javax.comm results unresolved and not available in the target platform (downloaded from your website).

I can resolve the package in Eclipse, but afterwards I can't build the project because the plugin javax.comm is unresolved.

**Is possible that an official target platform has already these problems from the beginning?**

Comment: What is your development environment? Which Target Platform are you using?

Comment: I've updated the question. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I suggest you to contact Eurotech support directly since ESF is the commercial version of Kura. You may wish to try [Kura's Developer's workspace](https://www.eclipse.org/kura/downloads.php) just to do a quick check on your machine

Comment: In this version ("uncommercial" kura) have you got any problem?

Comment: I worked with previous versions without problems. Many times it depends on Eclipse version, try using the exact version they suggest and Java7.
[ESF 4.0.2 is based on Kura 2.0.2](http://www.eurotech.com/DLA/Products_Eurotech/esf/RELEASE_NOTES.txt)

Comment: No problem with javax.comm and javax.microedition? Did you use in serial port communication?

Comment: Target Platform in Kura uses org.eclipse.soda.dk library, no idea actual ESF.